# Why can't my Unix terminal not find my matlab binaries and making Unix find them again?

Tags: shell, matlab

This happens to be a new problem because I was able to run MATLAB on the shell until today. I didn't install or update it or anything of that sort, but now I am unable run matlab in the sell. It tells me:

user~ $ matlab
bash: matlab: command not found

this seems weird to me.

The solution that I have tried is adding the MATLAB binaries to path. So I did:

PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app"

where `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app` is the path returned by matlabroot matlab command from the GUI. I tried this but as a no surprise, it didn't work, I still can't add the MATLAB binaries to my path. How does one find the MATLAB binaries location in my system? Even if I find them, is it advised to just manually add it to my path? I also restarted my computer (OS X) but that did not work either. Any advice how to solve the issue? Re-install MATLAB?

Comment: Try `PATH="$PATH":"/Applications/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin"`

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the location of your matlab binary using command:

```
find / -name matlab
```

Please note, larger the disk space you have, longer this command will run. If the binary is still on your system, you should get the actual location. Since I am not familiar with `matlabroot` command or any other command given to you by the application, I am not sure how trustable they are.

Also, I noticed you ran the `matlabroot` command without a path in the prefix. Which is telling me that your matlab binaries are searchable in the `PATH`. Which makes me think someone accidentally or knowingly deleted/moved the `matlab` binary

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your last paragraph. Why does that make you think it was moved? Btw, I did run the command you suggested and the amount of folders suggested are ridiculously large. Maybe I am better of just re-installing matlab.

Comment: First off run the command as such `find / -name matlab > /tmp/locations` and edit this `/tmp/locations` file and search for matlab in it, using your favorite text editor. Secondly, why I believe it is moved, because, generally all executable files are placed in the same directory for a given application, like `/opt/insert-application-name/bin` etc. My assumption is, you `matlab` binary and `matlabroot` binary were in the same directory at one time. This is an educated guess though. It might not hold true. Hence the assumption part.

Comment: `matlabroot` isn't a binary program - it's a function *within matlab*

Comment: @steeldriver, more the reason to believe, user has some way of running an executable from matlab related directories. User needs to find where the binaries are located and adjust the `PATH` variable accordingly.